# Allow www-data to create directories

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, security

How would I, with security in mind, allow `www-data` to create directories within `/var/www/html/assets/img` and its sub-directories?

I have a PHP script that automatically creates directories with 777 permissions, but `www-data` currently doesn't have the required permissions to allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the owner and group of that directory to `www-data` and setting permissions for owner/group to rwx

```
sudo chown -R www-data:wwwdata /var/www/html/assets/img
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/assets/img
```